# How to add an attribute or attribute sets on homepage magento. 1.9.0

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to add a custom search on frontend(magento). So i want to add 2 or 3 attributes on frontend to make a custom/advanced search. I have tried to add catalosearch/advanced to frontend but the attributes are not showing as dropdown menu like product page.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First make the attribute to be searcheable from admin. Catalog->attribute->manage attributes. Enable used in quick search and used in advanced search.
Then get all the searcheable attribute by this

```
$attributes = array();
foreach ($this->getSearchableAttributes() as $_attribute):
        $attributes[$_attribute->getAttributeCode()] = $_attribute;
endforeach;
```

Show the attribute by this $attributes['attribute_code'];

Comment: Hello, First of all thanks for answering Mr. Mohd.
I have enabled all searches for that attribute. But i'm  not undestanding that where i have to put that code i mean how i should use it or edit it. Can you please explain me a bit. I'm not that expert :/. Can i get an email address?.
Thanks.

Comment: Like you want to use it on advanced search then put this code in /app/design/frontend/your_theme/default/template/catalogsearch/advanced/form.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to click on  manage properties and check the frontend properties of that particular attribute. You just need to change the following :

Visible on Product View Page on Front-end - Yes

Makes the attribute searchable